# Cannot attach an entity that already exists

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am trying to update code via Linq, but I am getting this error:

> Cannot attach an entity that already exists.

C# code is here:

```
var con = (from c in cmsContentTable where c.ContentName == contentId
           select c).FirstOrDefault();  
cmsContentTable.Attach(con);  
con.ContentData = "New Value";  
cmsContentTable.Context.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't need to attach the entity, it already belongs to the context.

```
var con = (from c in cmsContentTable where c.ContentName == contentId select c).FirstOrDefault();
con.ContentData = "New Value";
cmsContentTable.Context.SubmitChanges();
```