# Cannot attach an entity that already exists

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

For the following code, getting the message:

> Cannot attach an entity that already exists.

C# code:

```
var con = (from c in cmsContentTable where c.ContentName == contentId select c).FirstOrDefault();
cmsContentTable.Attach(con);
con.ContentData = "New Value";
cmsContentTable.Context.SubmitChanges();
```

Why is it giving this error - Is this because a reference to con was already made
when

```
var con = (from c in cmsContentTable where c.ContentName == contentId select c).FirstOrDefault();
```

was done?

Comment: How about tagging this with your ORM framework?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot attach an entity that already exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605657/cannot-attach-an-entity-that-already-exists)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are already getting the item from the table:

```
var con = (from c in cmsContentTable where c.ContentName == contentId select    c).FirstOrDefault();
```

The context is already 'attached' to the object.  This is true whenever you pull an already existing object from a table.

If you remove the line:

```
cmsContentTable.Attach(con);
```

You should be fine.

A more helpful message would be "Cannot attach to an entity that is already attached to a context", as that is what is actually happening.